# How to get form control element by label?

Tags: angular, automated-tests, cypress

I have a form built from reusable components, such that each form control is generated with a unique `id` which is referenced by its label:

```
<label for="2346157937rfl5v">Complaint</label>
<div>
  <textarea id="2346157937rfl5v" [(ngModel)]="value"></textarea>
</div>
```

It's easy to use Cypress to identify the label element based on the text. But how can I then identify the associated form control element?

```
cy.contains('Complaint').???
```

I could just use `.next().get('textarea')`, but that seems too tied to the current implementation. Ideally there is some way to follow the link from the label.

---

Clarification: I want to identify the label element, get its `for` attribute, and then identify the textarea element using that `id`. This way the test isn't relying on the structure of the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution is pretty much optimal for plain Cypress.

If you want it built in, the package [cypress-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro/#examples) has label related find as one of it's paradigms,

```js
cy.findByLabelText(/Complaint/i)                // looks for the label
  .should('have.prop', 'tagName', 'TEXTAREA')   // yields the textarea
```

Comment: Thanks, that library looks like a great option!

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions that could help based on the assumption that you want a cleaner way to access the `textarea` element.

1. Using `eq`. If you have more than one text area and the position are fixed. You can directly access them.

```js
cy.get('textarea').eq(0) //Gets the first text area
```

2. I am assuming the id is re-generated with every compile. But If a part of your id remains constant, you can also use that to access your element.

```js
cy.get('textarea[id*="2346157"]')
```

3. Using `next()`

```js
cy.contains('label','Complaint').next().next() //gets the textarea
OR
cy.get('label[for="2346157937rfl5v"]').next().next()
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a few tips. Is there no way to follow the label's `for` attribute, though?

Comment: Do you mean you want to access the Complaint element using `for="2346157937rfl5v"` ?

Comment: I want to access the textarea with that id, yes.

Comment: If I understood correctly You can do like this `cy.get('label[for="2346157937rfl5v"]').next().next()`

Comment: That makes sense. I added a note to the question, hopefully it helps. I'm trying to avoid depending on the structure of the DOM, and just use the link between the label and the form control directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but it does seem to work. I'd prefer something cleaner, so hopefully this illustrates the goal.

```js
cy.contains('label', 'Complaint').then(label => {
  return cy.get(`#${label.attr('for')}`);
}).type('this is inside the textarea');
```

This approach identifies the label, then replaces the reference to the label with a reference to the element identified by the label's `for` attribute. So on the other side of `.then()`, the textarea is accessible.